# Is there a way to use conditional compilation symbols in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a c# project in which I'm reading different xmls. I have different conditional compilation symbols set, based on which I build two different .EXEs. Right now, what i'm doing is reading different xmls on the basis of the condition.

```
#if ABC_build
//read xml1
#else
//read xml2
#endif
```

But in this case, I have to include both the xmls with each build. Both the xmls are same except for two or three tags. Is there a way to write a single xml and to tell the compiler to include certain xml tags in a certain build and not the other?

Comment: For better understanding, please help us understand why do you want/need to define the conditions in pre-compile time and not in runtime with a simple "if"

Comment: In addition to the "why" that Luis asked for, please update your question to include the "how".  As in how are you reading the xml files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the XML files are not compiled, there is no such thing like Conditional Compilation. So I identify the fact that you have to include both XML files in the build output as the main problem you are trying to solve. 
What you can do is to adjust your build depending on the configuration, so that e.g. for a Debug build, file A is copied to the output folder and for a Release build file B.
In order to achieve this, you need to add similar code to your csproj-file:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
    <XmlInput Include="FileA.xml">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
    </XmlInput>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <XmlInput Include="FileB.xml">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
    </XmlInput>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <XmlOutput Include="$(OutputPath)\File.xml">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
    </XmlOutput>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(XmlInput)" DestinationFiles="@(XmlOutput)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BeforeClean">
    <Delete Files="@(XmlOutput)" />
  </Target>
```

This code adds an ItemGroup to the build that depends on the selected configuration. In the AfterBuild target, the file is copied to the output path. In the BeforeClean target, the file is removed again. In your code you don't need the conditional compilation anymore but have a common file name in the output folder that you can access.

In the sample, I added two XML files to the project (FileA.xml and FileB.xml). I reference them again as XmlOutput items in order to select the correct file to copy. As they are marked with Visible = false, they are not shown in solution explorer.

Comment: @Dv_MH: great to hear that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't tell the compiler to not read some xml tags. That is not a compile-time logic but rather a runtime-logic.

However, you can have boolean logic in the #if

```
#if (ABC_build || XYZ_build)
//read xml
#endif
```

Comment: I'm not using the same xml for both builds. If I use this conditional logic, there is not point of me having two seperate builds, is there?
I have only two builds. This wont work.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you can write a "conditional" XML file, that is preprocessed to produce different XML files based on parameters you supply.

One is to invent your own "conditional compilation tags" and write a little XSLT stylesheet to interpret them. For example it's common to see things like this:

```
<doc>
  <para use-when="windows">....</para>
  <para use-when="linux">....</para<
</doc>
```

and it's easy to write an XSLT code that copies the document retaining only those para's that are relevant.

Another way that many people use is XML external entities. I personally find these a bit inflexible.